# Open the keyboard when showing a prompt dialog

Tags: nativescript

After opening a prompt dialog, the input gets focus, but the keyboard won't show up until explicitly tapping the view. How can I make the keyboard show right away?

I've tried

```
const activity = app.android.foregroundActivity;
const context = app.android.currentContext;
// const token = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getWindowToken();
// const token = activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken();

context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE).showSoftInput(token, android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

uncommenting the first line instacrashes the app without any logs
uncommenting the second line tells me getWindowToken cannot be called on undefined (even if I put it in a timeout so that the dialog and its view are already showing and focused)

Comment: You could use directly the implemented method https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_utils_utils_.ad#showsoftinput